# OAUTH - Request Verified Email Address from LinkedIn

Tags: oauth, linkedin-api

So I'm getting the user's email address during login over OAUTH with LinkedIn as per https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/making-it-easier-you-develop-linkedin

However, it doesn't seem that there's any way to ensure this is a "verified" email address as opposed to one that anyone could pretend to claim.

Other providers I've used won't serve up the primary email address for a user if they've not verified, and in fact often won't Auth at all. LinkedIn however seems to.

Does anyone know if this is by design or if there's a workaround?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

check out the OAuth v2 they use now, it requires a validated email address.

Comment: Actually, I'd forgotten to post back. Yes, you're right. In fact the OAUTH1x flow is deprecated. It does have issues IMHO but LinkedIn just said they'd stopped supporting it. OAUTH2 is much easier anyway and works well.

Comment: Where can I find reference to this email being required as validated?  (It would be nice to have something at linkedin that points me to knowing this email is checked)

Comment: @DavidLjungMadison I wasn't able to find any documentation on this but I was able to confirm through testing that it works as expected -- see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that as of 6/20/2016, LinkedIn DOES NOT allow OAUTH authentication with accounts that do not have a verified email address.  If you try authenticate with LinkedIn you'll get the following error screen while allowing access:

[image: LinkedIn OAUTH error screen]

However, I was unable to find any official documentation on this matter.

Comment: Did you got any idea for this issue ?

Comment: I never found any official documentation, but I was satisfied from my testing that email confirmation was a requirement for using LinkedIn for OAuth.